# Transform regex with character classes and repetitions to its most basic ASCII form

Tags: regex

Is there a way, a regular expression maybe or even a library, which can transform a regular expression with character classes and repetition to its most basic ASCII form.

For example I'd like to have the following conversions:

```
\d -> [0-9]
\w -> [A-Za-z0-9_]
\s -> [ \t\r\n\v\f]
\d{2} -> [0-9][0-9]
\d{3,} -> [0-9][0-9][0-9]+
\d{,3} -> I dont even know how to show this...
```

Comment: `\d{,3}` could be represented as `[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?`

Comment: I want to convert a java-regex to a regex which I can use in the basic awk.

Comment: Note that basic standard awk supports `{n,p}`. With GNU awk though, you need to pass POSIXLY_CORRECT=anything to its environment. The `\d`, `\w`... above are easy to translate, but some like non-greedy repeating operators cannot be translated to awk EREs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a commercial product called [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) that lets you enter a regex in their syntax and then generate the version for any of a number of popular systems.  There may be something similar out there for free, or you could write your own.

At its most basic, a regular expression syntax only needs two things: alternation (OR) and closure (STAR).  Well, and grouping.  OK, three things. Other common operators are just shortcuts, really:

```
x+ = xx*
x? = (|x)
[xyz] = (x|y|z)
```

*etc*.

Things like `\d` just map to character classes and then to alternations.  Negated character classes and `.` map to very big alternations. :)

There are some features that don't translate, however, such as lookaround.  Mapping those to something that works without the feature is not readily automatable; it will depend upon the particular circumstances motivating their use.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd have to define which transformations you want to do. As written in the comments, not all advanced features can be written in terms of simpler operators. For example, the lookaround operators have no substitute. So you're limited by the target regexp parser anyway.

Then, with this list of transformations, you should simply apply them. They can probably be written as regexps themselves, but it might be easier to write a script in Python or so to actually parse (but not evaluate) the regexp. Then it can write it back with the requested transformations applied. And bark at you if you've used too complex features.

This wouldn't be too hard, but I'm not so sure if it would be very useful either. If you need powerful regexps, use a better regexp engine. It should be easy to write a simple Python or Perl script instead of a simple Awk script, for example.

Comment: `The lookaround operators have no substitute` - for checking whether something matches or not, I'm not sure for all cases, but at least I know simple case can be converted to the theoretical regular expression (alternation, concatenation, closure, grouping). I think it will not be convertible if the regex is used to match text.

Comment: @nhahtdh: In some (or many?) cases, you are probably right, but I don't think it's always possible, especially with negative lookbehind. And when it is possible, it seems non-trivial to define the required substitution in a general way.

Comment: `especially with negative lookbehind` I wonder how it may be harder than lookahead? (again, for checking only). `And when it is possible, it seems non-trivial to define the required substitution in a general way.` Agree. A regex that checks that a string does not contains substring "abc" is very complicated without lookaround.